# Symfony FOSUserBundle - include login form in layout template

Tags: php, symfony1, twig

We've successfully configured the FOSUserBundle; login, register, reset password, etc, are all working just fine.

Now we want to incorporate the login form into our general site layout, notably placing the form into the top-right section of the layout header. Doing this would be easy enough if we were just dealing with the username and password fields. However we can't seem to figure out how to obtain the CSRF token which is generated by the FOSUserBundle service:

```
$this->container->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken('authenticate');
```

I tried calling the above within a Twig extension which otherwise works fine however apparently the extension can't properly reference the container.

Surely there is some easy way to obtain the FOSUserBundle CSRF token globally?

Thanks!
Jason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a function like this in one of your controllers

```
public function getTokenAction()
{
    return new Response($this->container->get('form.csrf_provider')
                            ->generateCsrfToken('authenticate'));
}
```

and then just embed it into your form via

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{% render('YourBundle:YourController:getToken') %}" />
```

You also need to include the following at the top of your controller:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
```

Answer (score 45):

**Symfony 2.3:**

One possible solution would be to define the csrf provider as a Twig global variable like this:

```
twig:
    globals:
        fos_csrf_provider: "@form.csrf_provider"
```

And then in your layout call it like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ fos_csrf_provider.generateCsrfToken('authenticate') }}" />
```

So you don't need to call any controller.

**Symfony 2.4 and later:**

```
twig:
    globals:
        fos_csrf_provider: "@security.csrf.token_manager"
```

and:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ fos_csrf_provider.refreshToken('authenticate') }}" />
```

Comment: This should be marked as the best answer - cleaner and easier than the other one.

Comment: This is the best and cleanest solution. Render controller in templates consume a lot of resources: this solution is the best and cleanest one.

Comment: Is this the same for Symfony 3.2?

Comment: @RodolVelasco "*Symfony 2.4 and later:*" - try it, not much code