# Variable "csrf_token" does not exist in ::base.html.twig

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

Symfony2 and FOS User Bundle issue...

I have implemented my own login form in the head of the page (using FOS User Bundle as per directions in http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=37767.)

Now, I have the error message

```
Variable "csrf_token" does not exist in ::base.html.twig
```

Someone else on that forum (url above) had the exact same issue, and resolved it by putting in the hidden csrf field like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
```

My problem though is: that works fine when on the /login path, but my whole point is not needing that separate login page, I want my form integrated in the page head always, and it seems that the {{csrf_token}} is only available when the page is rendered by the login controller...

Also, how do I get the error messages (flashes) in there, I assume I must include the login controller in my defaultController somehow, to get all those variables with it every time, or...? Or should I instead render the userBundle controller in that portion of the header instead of pasting some of the userBundle template into my head?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you create your own login form using the Form component then you should already have a csrf token as a hidden field. The reason that the `csrf_token` variable is available only on /login is because the default FOSUserBundle login controller doesn't use a form, instead they just generate a csrf token manually as seen [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php#L43) and pass it to the view.

So, either make sure you are rendering all the hidden fields on your form with something like `{{ form_rest(form) }}` or generate a csrf_token manually like the FOSUserBundle does [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php#L43) and render it with the code you already have.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a working csrf controller from within your controller, please [see a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903114/symfony-fosuserbundle-include-login-form-in-layout-template).

This example allowed me to fix the issue you were having. Let this be reference to anyone else extending the FOS User bundle form.