# Invalid CSRF token on my own login form

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm working on a symfony application using FOSUserBundle. I want to have a dropdown login form in the menubar if i am not authenticated, which have a complete different style that the one under /login.

I'm getting 'Invalid CSRF token'. I'm a complete newbie to symfony2, so maybe i'm making an obvious mistake, but i can't find a solution googling. This is what i tried:

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace RoiRodriguez\CustomUserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class DefaultController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Para requests internos, renderiza la barra de navegación.
     * No tiene ruta.
     */
    public function navigationAction() {
        $params = array (
                'csrf_token' => '',
                'last_username' => '' 
        );

        if ($this->container->get ( 'security.context' )->isGranted ( 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY' )) {
            $session = $this->getRequest ()->getSession ();
            $params ['last_username'] = (null === $session) ? '' : $session->get ( SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME );
            $params ['csrf_token'] = $this->container->get ( 'form.csrf_provider' )->generateCsrfToken ( 'authenticate' );
        }

        return $this->render ( 'CustomUserBundle:Default:navigation.html.twig', $params );
    }
}
```

View:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
{% if app.user and app.user.isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}
    {% include 'CustomUserBundle:Default:includes/navigation-authenticated.html.twig' %}
{% else %}
    {% include 'CustomUserBundle:Default:includes/navigation-notauthenticated.html.twig' with {'csrf_token': csrf_token, 'last_username': last_username} %}
{% endif %}
</ul>
```

Not authenticated template:

```
<li><a href="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}">Nueva cuenta</a></li>
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
    data-toggle="dropdown">Ingresar <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dd-login-form-container">

        <!-- login form -->
        <form role="form" method="post"
            action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
......
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresa!</button>
        </form>
        <!-- end login form -->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{{ path('fos_user_resetting_request') }}">¿Has olvidado
                    tu contraseña?</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}">¿Todavía
                    no tienes una cuenta?</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

What am i missing? Also: This dropdown menu gets rendered inside /login too, would i have any trouble with generating the token twice there?

Comment: I am pretty new to Symfony but can you try setting csrf_token to false, may be it will work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony FOSUserBundle - include login form in layout template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903114/symfony-fosuserbundle-include-login-form-in-layout-template)

Answer (score 16):

My custom login form was giving me the same issue - 'Invalid CSRF token' -  anytime I tried to log in. After going through the documentation for the FOSUserBundle configuration options([FOSUserBundle Configuration Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/configuration_reference.html)), I discovered that the bundle enables a different token manager by default. So I went to my security.yml file and commented out the line specifying a csrf token generator for the login form.

Here is a cross section of my app/config/security.yml file with the configuration specifying the crsf token manager comment out.

```
security:

.......

firewalls:

    ........

    vendor:
        pattern: ^/vendor
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
        #   csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            login_path: vendor_login
            check_path: vendor_login_check
        logout: true
```

After doing this, my login form started working and I could log in.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the best and cleanest solution for this problem: **set the csrf provider as a Twig global variable**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17233953/1399706

Comment: Are you implying this question is a duplicate? :-)

Comment: @Potherca CV pls. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in the past...

```
<form action="{{ path('yourRoute') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
```

The CSRF token was invalide because i didn't insert `{{ form_enctype(form) }}`

You should take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-enctype-view because this way will be removed soon...

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Strange that it only started giving me issues a full year after I created the project, though.

Answer (score 1):

@Roirodriguez, your code help me get throught this. I think you just needed to call the render method instead of the include (my step 4).

I wanted to do a simple login form on my header, if any error occurred it will redirect you to the FOSUserBundle normal login page providing feedback. After the user was authenticated I wanted a dropdown with the username, when opened more options would showup (logout link, etc.)

Here is how I manage to get it working:

1. **Created a Child bundle of the FOSUserBundle**. I Created a new bundle name UserBundle and then used the get parent method. [link to FOSUserBundle docs](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md)

   ```
   <?php 
   namespace Me\UserBundle;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
   class MeUserBundle extends Bundle
   {
       public function getParent()
       {
           return 'FOSUserBundle';
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Create Templates** Created a new template for this new login form and the authenticated dropdown

   ```
   {#loginHorizontal.html.twig#}

   {% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}
   <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <form  class="navbar-form navbar-left form-inline" action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post" role="form" >
       <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
       <div class="form-group">
           <div class="input-group">
               <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user" ></i></div>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt_username"
                      placeholder="{{ 'security.login.username'|trans }}" name="_username"
                      value="{{ last_username }}" required="required" >
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <div class="input-group">
               <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-asterisk" ></i></div>
               <input type="password"  class="form-control" id="txt_pwd" name="_password" required="required" placeholder="{{ 'security.login.password'|trans }}" />
           </div>

       </div>
       <input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit"  class="btn btn-primary" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans }}" />
       <br />
       <div class="checkbox">
           <label>
               <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" /> {{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans }}
           </label>
       </div>
   </form>
   </div>



   {#authenticadedDropdown.html.twig#}

   {% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
       <li class="dropdown">
           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> welcome, {{ app.user.username }}<span class="caret"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
               <li><a href="#">bla bla</a></li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li><a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}">
                   {{ 'layout.logout'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
               </a></li>
           </ul>
       </li>
       <li></li>
   </ul>
   ```
3. **Overided the SecurityController and create actions** Overide the controller and Created a new Action that renders this template which creates and sends the vars csrf_token & username as parameters for the login.

   ```
   namespace Me\UserBundle\Controller;

   use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController as BaseController;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
   use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;


   class SecurityController extends BaseController
   {
       /**
        * For internal template use: Renders the Horizontal Login ej. Header bar login.
        * No routing used.
        */
       public function loginHorizontalAction(Request $request)
       {
           /** @var $session \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session */
           $session = $request->getSession();

           // last username entered by the user
           $lastUsername = (null === $session) ? '' : $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::LAST_USERNAME);

           $csrfToken = $this->container->has('form.csrf_provider')
               ? $this->container->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken('authenticate')
               : null;

           $data =  array(
               'last_username' => $lastUsername,
               'csrf_token' => $csrfToken,
           );
           return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('MeUserBundle:Security:loginHorizontal.html.twig', $data);
       }

       /**
        * For internal template use: Renders the Dropdown after authentication ej. Header bar for user.
        * No routing used.
        */
       public function authenticatedDropdownAction()
       {
           $data =  array();
           return $this->container->get('templating')
               ->renderResponse('MeUserBundle:Security:authenticatedDropdown.html.twig', $data);
       }
   }
   ```
4. **Embed controller action** Finally I embeded/renderes via the twig template this newly created controller´s action [Symfony doc on how to embed controller actions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers)

   ```
   <div class="navbar-right" >
       {% block login %}
           {% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
               {% render(controller("MeUserBundle:Security:authenticatedDropdown")) %}
           {% else %}
               {% render(controller("MeUserBundle:Security:loginHorizontal")) %}
           {% endif %}
       {% endblock %}
   </div>
   ```

I know it been a while since your post, but hope this helps.

Cheers,
Pancho

Answer (score 0):

I run into this topic when searching for a solution with symfony 4 and FOSUserBundle while overriding a login template.

For me the following worked:

in the login_content.html.twig i found:

```
{% if csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
{% endif %}
```

I have replaced it with:

```
{% if csrf_token('authenticate') %}
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}" />
{% endif %}
```

*note: the extra "('authenticate')"*

and now i get a crsf token. and before this was empty.

Hopefully this will help other aswell.